# How can I add a button in a footnote in Google Glass?

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I'm trying to implement a footnote along with couple of buttons inside the footer.

```
Card card1.setFootnote("Footer");

Button btnSave = new Button(this)
Button btnClear = new Button(this)

card1.setButton(btnSave);   //no option to put into card at footer
card1.setButton(btnClear);  //no option to put into card at footer
```

How could I do this?

Answer (score 2):

While you could modify the view hierarchy that gets returned by `Card.toView()` to insert whatever widgets you want, consider that this isn't the best approach for user interaction. Since Glass does not provide a touch screen, `Button` widgets make little sense on that form factor.

A better approach would be to add an options menu with your actions that would be presented when the user taps on the touchpad.

Answer (score -1):

If you really want to do that Rakesk then i suggest you design your layout in landscape using xml. Size of that layout should be relative to **640 x 480 resolution**. In this way you can add as many widgets in the UI as you want though it is not recommended.